# Fatal error: Call to a member function getHardDrive() on null

Tags: magento1.9.3.7

I am getting this error on all my product pages. I have not sure what is going on as it was fine the other day. The only thing I have add was **magmi** for product updates. removed this and I still get the below error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getHardDrive() on null in
>   /volume1/web/magento/app/design/frontend/athlete/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
>   on line 52

```
<?php echo $_item->getHardDrive(); ?>
```

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: is there product attribute named `hard_drive` exist in your store?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<?php echo $_item->getHardDrive(); ?>
```

with:

```
<?php echo $_item->getHardDrive() ? $_item->getHardDrive():''; ?>
```